# How to control the width of longtable

Tags: longtable, width

That's very strange why the sum of the width of each column does not equal the total width of longtable. I have two tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\textwidth 15.95cm
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{
    |p{0.25cm}
    |p{4.6cm}
    |p{2 cm}
    |p{2.2cm}
    |p{0.8cm}
    |p{2.1cm}
    |p{1.9cm}|
    }
    \multicolumn{7}{>{\centering}p{\textwidth}}{1
    }\tabularnewline\hline
    a & a & a & a & a & a & a
    \tabularnewline\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{
    | >{\centering}p{13cm}
    | >{\raggedright}p{9.cm}
    | >{\raggedright}p{2.42cm}
    | >{\raggedright}p{2.42cm} |
    }
    \multicolumn{4}{>{\centering}p{\textwidth}}{
    2
    }\tabularnewline\hline
    a & a & a & a
    \tabularnewline\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}


\end{docume
```

Two tables in the PDF exactly have same widths.

As  marmot said the total width of a table should be

`sum of columns + (n-1)*\arraycolsep`

And how to know the value of `\arraycolsep`?

More generally, how to make all the tables in the PDF has same widths? And what's the meaning of width `\textwidth` in `\multicolumn{7}{>{\centering}p{\textwidth}}`.

Moreover, when I decrease the width of some columns, the width of first line of table will decrease and the second line will not change; when I increase the width of some columns, both first and second lines will increase?

Comment: please provide complete small document (mwe: minimal working example)  which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Yes, the width means the width of the texts in the columns. `\arraycolsep` gets added.

Comment: @marmot but why two tables have same sums of widths of columns, but have different total widths showed in PDF?

Comment: Simply because there is an additional term `(n-1)*\arraycolsep` where `n` is the number of columns.

Comment: @marmot so that! How to know the value of `\arraycolsep`? And usually how do we make all the tables have same widths? Since there is another width called `\textwidth` in my examples. Could you write a detailed answer below then I can select your answer.

Comment: It is next-to-impossible to write an answer since your question does not contain an MWE, i.e. a small compilable document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. One would have to guess too many things.

Comment: @marmot I have updated the MWE

Comment: your tables has more issues. (i) sum of column width are not equal to `\textwidth ` (15.95 cm), (ii) width of the multi column cells are equal to `\textwidth`, so it extend lats column that the width of the whole table can be equal to `\textwidth`.

Comment: @Zarko what's the difference between width of multi column and width of sum? Do you mean if they are not equal, then last column will automatically choose the width to make the sum equal to \textwidth?

Comment: @user6703592, yes, i mean this. i will try demonstrate this answer.

Comment: @Zarko  About as we said the width equals to `sum of columns + (n-1)*\arraycolsep` and we don't know the value of `\arraycolsep.` And how about when the sum is larger than `\textwidth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your tables has more issues.

- sum of column width are not equal to `\textwidth` (15.95 cm),
- width of the multi column cells are equal to `\textwidth`, so it extend lats column that the width of the whole table is equal to `\textwidth`
- in examples below are in determination of columns width considered `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[hmargin=2.525cm]{geometry}%
  %\textwidth 15.95cm

  \usepackage{array, longtable}
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}  p{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

  %-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
  \begin{document}
  %\begin{center}
  width of table determined by sum of column width

  \begin{longtable}{
  |p{\dimexpr0.25cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr4.6cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2 cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2.2cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr0.8cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2.1cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr1.9cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}|
  }
  %\multicolumn{7}{|C{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{1}
  \hline
  a & a & a & a & a & a & a   \\
  \hline
  \end{longtable}
  %\end{center}

  width of table determined by multi column cell width

  \begin{longtable}{
  |p{\dimexpr0.25cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr4.6cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2 cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2.2cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr0.8cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2.1cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr1.9cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}|
  }
  \multicolumn{7}{|C{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{1}    \\
  \hline
  a & a & a & a & a & a & a   \\
  \hline
  \end{longtable}


  width of the multi column cell is adopted to sum of ll columns widths

  \begin{longtable}{
  |p{\dimexpr0.25cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr4.6cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2 cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2.2cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr0.8cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr2.1cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}
  |p{\dimexpr1.9cm-2\tabcolsep-1.13\arrayrulewidth}|
  }
  \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{1}    \\
  \hline
  a & a & a & a & a & a & a   \\
  \hline
  \end{longtable}

  second table:

  %\begin{center}
  \begin{longtable}{
  | C{\dimexpr1.3cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}% 13cm
  | R{\dimexpr9.0cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}
  | R{\dimexpr2.42cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}
  | R{\dimexpr2.42cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth} |
  }
  %\multicolumn{4}{|C{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{2}
  \hline
  a & a & a & a   \\
  \hline
  \end{longtable}
  %\end{center}

  \begin{longtable}{
  | C{\dimexpr1.3cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}% 13cm
  | R{\dimexpr9.0cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}
  | R{\dimexpr2.42cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}
  | R{\dimexpr2.42cm-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth} |
  }
  \multicolumn{4}{|C{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{2}    \\
  \hline
  a & a & a & a   \\
  \hline
  \end{longtable}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicates border of text area).

the first and second table without of multi column cells have different widths. the purpose of the first table row is not clear. see if the third version of the first table gives what you like to achieve.

Comment: what's the meanings of `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`? And I still don't understand the logic why table1 and table 2 have the same width?

Comment: @user6703592, `\tabcolsep` is distance between cell content to cell border (vertical line in your case), `\arrayrulewidth` width of lines in table. both you can define width `\setlength\tabcolsep{<desired distance>}` and `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{<desired width>}` . their default values are `5pt` and `015pt` if i remember correctly.

Comment: why do you use the coefficient `1.13` and `1.25` for `\arrayrulewidt` ?

Comment: and except for the manually calculating, is there any way to make two tables with different number of columns having same widths?

Comment: (i) `1.13` is approx. `8 lines/7 columns`, i e. width of eight vertical lines  divided to seven columns, similarly for `1.25 ~ 5/4`. (ii) with use of `tabularx` environment. see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Comment: so we should use `tabularx` and cannot use `longtable`?

Comment: why you like to use `longtable`? are your table really so long that cant be fit in one page? `ltablex` is combination of `longtable` and `tabulary`. Maybe it will can help you. i suggest you to ask new question. i'm pretty sure, that for this question my answer is satisfactory..